# How to install Dreamboxedit, Clonezilla and Skype in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: software-installation

How to install Dreamboxedit, Clonezilla and Skype in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Comment: Use Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Pretty sure Clonezilla is bootable-disk-only, so I'm unsure of what your intended use is, but Skype is available from their website (don't know why this wouldn't be the first place to check) and Dreamboxedit can most likely be found in the Software Center. Exactly how much research did you do before you asked this?

Comment: Sorry, newbie, want too much. Had serious pc problems during last weeks. Now Ubuntu is new for me... Thanks.